# How can I get rid of "array[], dtype='<U12'

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I am making a code to analyze the frequencies of the sells of different products (StockCode), so this is the code to get the frequencies:

```
stockCode = df['StockCode'].values.tolist()

non_repeated_list = []
frequencies = []
list2d= []

for i in stockCode:
    if i not in non_repeated_list:
        non_repeated_list.append(i)

for i in non_repeated_list:
    a = stockCode.count(i)
    frequencies.append(a)
```

And then stack both lists in a 2D list with `list2d = np.column_stack((non_repeated_list, frequencies))` so I can sort them with:

```
print(sorted(list2d,key=lambda x:x[-1], reverse=True))
```

But when I print it out it says:

```
[array(['22139', '993'], dtype='<U12'), array(['22911', '99'], dtype='<U12'), array(['17012D', '99'], dtype='<U12')...
```

So I wanteed to ask, how can I get just the rows between the []?

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe ? I think, the for loops are not required. We can get it directly from dataframe.

Comment: Don't think in terms of 'getting rid of' this display notation or that.  The display is secondary, a product of what the printed object is.  Try to understand what the display is showing.  Here you have a list  (or array) of arrays, each of which contains strings. Look at `non_repeated_list` and `frequencies` separately.  Do you really need to combine them into one array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a minimal, reproducible example, I'll try to recreate one.

I'm guessing `df` is a dataframe, and `df['StockCode']` is Series containing strings:

```
In [287]: ds = pd.Series(['one','two','one','three','two'])                                            
In [288]: ds                                                                                           
Out[288]: 
0      one
1      two
2      one
3    three
4      two
dtype: object
```

then we get a list of strings:

```
In [289]: x = ds.values.tolist()                                                                       
In [290]: x                                                                                            
Out[290]: ['one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'two']
```

and find the unique ones:

```
In [291]: alist = []                                                                                   
In [292]: for i in x: 
     ...:     if i not in alist: 
     ...:         alist.append(i) 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [293]: alist                                                                                        
Out[293]: ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

and count them:

```
In [294]: freq = []                                                                                    
In [295]: for i in alist: 
     ...:     freq.append(x.count(i)) 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [296]: freq                                                                                         
Out[296]: [2, 2, 1]
```

column_stack of the two strings produces a 2d array, string dtype:

```
In [297]: np.column_stack((alist, freq))                                                               
Out[297]: 
array([['one', '2'],
       ['two', '2'],
       ['three', '1']], dtype='<U21')
```

`column_stack` can't produce a list or array of arrays, so you must be doing something more.

Python `sorted` will treat the array as a list, the same as `list(..), or a list comprehension on the 2d array:

```
In [298]: [a for a in _]                                                                               
Out[298]: 
[array(['one', '2'], dtype='<U21'),
 array(['two', '2'], dtype='<U21'),
 array(['three', '1'], dtype='<U21')]
```

You could rejoin the arrays with:

```
In [299]: np.vstack(_)                                                                                 
Out[299]: 
array([['one', '2'],
       ['two', '2'],
       ['three', '1']], dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I forgot to put the code I used to sort it by the frequencies, I just edited it